# After predicting a Random Forest how do I spatially project predictions onto a raster?

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, gis

After making a random forest model of nitrate prediction from a set of 11 (categorical and continuous) explanatory variables I want to visualize these projections spatially on a map. Most of the explanatory variables I am using are factor variables from raster layers but not all of them - some are point data. I could export the raster layers from GIS into R but then what? Would the opposite be easier, joining predictions to a layer and making the map in GIS? I cannot find any resources on how to do this online for a beginner.

Comment: Can you tell me what the x and y axes of the map are?  Are you thinking about something like tf-idf or similar?  Can you give dummy input, output, and code?  This helps answers to be more relevant and informative for others.  What have you tried to do so far?

Comment: The x and Y axis would be longitude and latitude. I don't know where to begin so the only thing I have done is I have installed the raster package in R.